# sugar crm community edition REST calls

Tags: java, rest, sugarcrm

I had configured SugarCRM community version 6.5.23 in WAMP server in my windows systems. This community edition is completely having PHP files. Now i need to access this application through REST calls. I need to get OAUTH token and then need to create new accounts through REST calls only.

In demo version i can able to do these REST calls through rest clients using below URL.

http://{site url}/rest/v10/

But in community edition these end point is not working. In documentation they have mentioned like we can use below URL.

http://{site url}/sugarcrm/service/v2/rest.php

How can i do rest call for above URL in JAVA or through REST client plugin. In REST client plugin if i use above URL its returning PHP code only.

Please help me how i can do the REST calls through either rest client plugin or JAVA to my community edition.

Comment: Did you install PHP on your server and configure the web server to use it?

Comment: Hi.. Yes i had installed PHP and i had followed installation steps for sugarcrm community edition. Now the UI is showing up and i can able to login through admin credentials. Do we need to configure web server for this seperately? can you let me know where we can do that?